# How can I get the output of a process launched with RunTime.exec() using rundll32 url.dll?

Tags: java

I just learned about using `Runtime.exec()` to launch a process with Java and I have a couple of questions that I haven't been able to find answers for.
If a program executes:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll , FileProtocolHandler" + myProgram);
p.waitFor();
```

Is there any way to obtain a reference to `myProgram`? `p` points to the process that opens `myProgram`, not to `myProgram`. What I want is a way to get the output from `myProgram`. 
Additionally, `waitFor()` blocks until p has terminated. Assuming that `myProgram` launched successfully, can I be sure that it has been launched at the time `P.waitFor()` returns?

Comment: This can't be right `"rundll32 url.dll `... I'm missing, at least, an end-quote

Comment: Fixed. I did not realize the argument was a single string.

Comment: I would reckon, before the `p.waitFor()` you insert, `p.getInputStream()`